# Clicking on Submit Button in div doesn't set attribute display to be none

Tags: java, selenium

Using Selenium Webdriver when trying to click on a submit button child inside of a popup div that is not in another iFrame. The parent popup div does not get the attribute "display" set back to none.

The button has a ID assigned and I am using PageFactory model to discover elements. I have tried using Actions(), JavaScriptExecutor() classes and plain old .click() function, but the div is not getting set back to "none" after the action/click is performed by the webdriver.

Element:

```
<button _ngcontent-c2="" id="policyEntry-clickYes" label="OK" pbutton="" 
type="button" ng-reflect-label="OK" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state- 
default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"><span class="ui-button-text ui 
clickable">OK</span></button>

@FindBy(id = "policyEntry-clickYes")
public WebElement confirmationOkBtn;
```

Action Used:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(PolicyEntryPage.confirmationOkBtn).click().perform();
```

JavascriptExecutor:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", PolicyEntryPage.confirmationOkBtn);
```

DIV that needs to swap back and forth:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-confirmdialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" style="display: none; width: 425px; visibility: visible; left: 627.5px; top: 394px; z-index: 1046; opacity: 0;"></div>
```

The div that surrounds the popup should be set back to display:none from display:block after clicking the confirmation button.

NOTE: The functionality works manually.

Comment: if possible try once with keyboard actions like enter..

Comment: @muraliselenium policyEntryPage.confirmationOkBtn.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); Doesn't work either div still set to display:block with the opacity set to 100.